# On the domain of convergence of usual definition of Riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, limits-and-convergence

If we define Riemann zeta function as it is usually defined so that $$\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-s\ln n}$$ then we can rewrite it as:

$$\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^x}\cos(y\ln n) - i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^x} \sin(y\ln n)=w_1(x,y)-iw_2(x,y)$$:

It is known that for $y=0$ both $w_1$ and $w_2$ converge if $x \in (1,+\infty)$ because when $y=0$ we get domain of absolute convergence of $\zeta$.

Now, the question is what about the set of all $y$ such that both $w_1$ and $w_2$ converge for all $x$ in some interval (where the interval is dependent upon $y$ and is pushed beyond $\Re (s) >1$), in other words, the set of all $y$ such that $\zeta (s)$ defined as $\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-s\ln n}$ converges for all $x$ in some interval, so i raise the following question:

Is it true that for every $y\ne 0$ there is $0<\varepsilon<1$ (or we could write $\varepsilon(y)$ because of the dependence of $\varepsilon$ on $y$) such that $w_1$ and $w_2$ both converge for all $x \in (1-\varepsilon (y),+\infty)$?

So the question is about pushing the boundary of absolute convergence to the natural boundary of convergence of the formula that is used almost everywhere as a definition of Riemann zeta for $\Re (s) >1$.

Comment: No, it's not true.  When $y \neq 0$, the real and imaginary parts are basically power series in $e^{-x}$ (with non-integral powers) whose coefficients tend to be near 1.  Note that $w_2$ is identically zero on the real line.

Comment: But when $y \neq 0$ then real and imaginary parts have nonvanishing sine and cosine terms which for every $y \neq 0$ and different $n$ may in some way oscillate in $+$ and $-$ signs so they could make the series convergent, right?

Comment: I see, you are asking for a non-uniform pointwise convergence of a rapidly oscillating sum, for all points in an open interval.  I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: This is a Dirichlet series, and it diverges for $s=1$, hence it diverges for all $s$ with $\operatorname{Re}s<1$.

Comment: @ Emil Jeřábek It diverges for $s=1$ because $1$ is a complex number whose imaginary part is zero and because harmonic series is divergent series, I do not see the reason why $w_1$ and $w_2$ should diverge for every complex number $s$ such that $\operatorname{Re}s<1$ if imaginary part is not zero?

Comment: The basic idea is that for every $y\ne 0$ the series $w_1$ and $w_2$ are. as I believe, both convergent for every $x$ greater than some $1-\varepsilon(y)$, where $0<\varepsilon(y)<1$.

Answer (score 3):

I would have put this in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment. So here it is:
If a  Dirichlet-Reihe $L(s)$ converges for some $s=s_0$, no matter if absolute or not, then it converges locally uniformly in every domain of the form $\{ s_0+z: |\arg(z)|<\frac\pi 2-\delta\}$, $\delta>0$ and therefore represents a holomorphic function in the domain $\Re(s)>\Re(s_0)$.
As the Riemann zeta function has a pole at $s=1$, the series never converges for $\Re(s)<1$.

Comment: But how do you know that there is no pair $(x,y)$ such that $y\ne 0$ and $x \in (1-\varepsilon, + \infty)$ and $0< \varepsilon <1$ such that both $w_1$ and $w_2$ converge, no matter absolutely or not?

Comment: because then the Dirichlet-series would converge in the point $s_0=x+iy$.

Comment: I am not sure if you (and me also) understand correctly the contrapositive statement (if that is your aim) of the theorem that you mention in your answer, look more carefully, I think that I do not say that $w_1$ and $w_2$ converge locally uniformly in every domain of the above form.

Comment: No matter whether you aim at the contrapositive or not I still do not take this answer as a satisfactory one.

Comment: This is the same argument I gave in the comments. Ante, I’m afraid *you* do not understand correctly the contrapositive. The fact that the series converges uniformly in Stolz angles is a *consequence* of its convergence at the tip of the angle, not an assumption.

Comment: See e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet_Series_Convergence_Lemma or http://planetmath.org/node/34764 .

Comment: One more comment: the Dirichlet series argument does not determine for which points $1+it$ at the line of convergence the series converges. For Riemann zeta and similar series, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84097 shows the answer is *never*. That is, the $\zeta(s)$ series only converges for $\operatorname{Re}s>1$.